# RxJava: Passing nested data along from a single Observable

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

[RxJava version 3]

The link below shows how to pass variables along when chaining observables using nested observables:

[In RxJava, how to pass a variable along when chaining observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176072/in-rxjava-how-to-pass-a-variable-along-when-chaining-observables)

However, it does not seem to work when the data all comes from a single observable. For example, in a data structure:

```
obs.flatMap(dataStructure ->
            obs.map(dataStructure1 ->
                    dataStructure1.b).map(b ->
                        foobar(dataStructure.a, b)));
```

Presumably this does not work because I am trying to take from the same observable twice, it processes all combinations of a and b twice. Apart from all that it seems ugly, is there a simple way to achieve what I want while being able to arbitrarily add things to the chain (e.g. do more operations to b before calling foobar)?

Comment: How is it not working? Do you want to avoid subscribing to `obs` multiple times? This does one round of combinations: `range(1, 10).flatMap(a -> range(1, 10).map(b -> println(a + ", " + b))).subscribe();`.

Comment: I'm not trying to get any combinations beyond those that already exist,
In your example, I want `1, 1 2, 2 3, 3` etc. for a total of 10 prints.
I am aware I could achieve this with 
`Observable<Integer> range = Observable.range(1, 10);
        range.zipWith(range, (a, b) -> a + ", " + b)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);`
However, I am asking if there is a way to do this with the nested observable approach rather than with zipWith.

Comment: I don't understand. With zip, you get `a.a` and `b.b` so what specific data access you try to get from some nesting?

Comment: Remember I said a single observable, so I don't want `a.a` and `b.b`, I want `a.a` and `a.b`. Though I am no longer sure if it matters in this context.
I'm trying to process the 2 fields separately and then recombine them at the end using nested observables rather than ZipWith.
So imperatively, this is simply `a = stream.next(); println(a.a + ", " + a.b)` in a for loop.

Comment: Process how? Why not simply call `obs.doOnNext(a -> println(a.a + ", " + a.b))` where you process an item from obs? Do you have dependent reactive processing for `a.a` and `a.b`? Perhaps some form of [async mapping](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJavaExtensions#flowabletransformersmapasync)?

Comment: I achieved what I wanted with the following:
`range(1, 10).flatMap(a -> just(a).map(/** do things to a **/).map(b -> a + ", " + b));`
I'm not sure if that helps?

Comment: Makes no sense if you have synchronous inner in `flatMap`.

Comment: Is there a simpler way to achieve the desired output then?
Like, let's say I did this:
`range(1, 10).flatMap(a -> just(a).map(a -> a*a).map(b -> a + ", " + b));`

Output would be: 
1, 1
2, 4
3, 9
4, 16
etc.

Comment: Do a straightforward `map` with the expression: `range.map(a -> a + ", " + (a * a))`.

Comment: Have you tried this library? https://github.com/pakoito/Komprehensions It was created specially to simplify call chains.